# How to make a popup appear on the side/bottom of the page instead of the center?

Tags: javascript

I'm still very new to Drupal and I've been trying to get a popup to appear on my page in a specific location. Popup on load (https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_onload) does pretty much everything I want, except that it appears in the middle of the screen. Anyone know what I can do so that it'll appear on the side or bottom of the screen? Or know another module out there that has this kind of configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The Popup on Load module leverages the [Colorbox module](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox), and its jQuery plugin dependency, to style the pop up. The module allows for your own custom style which will let you adjust the popup position to where you want it. This is covered in [its documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1971564).

> **Add a custom Colorbox style to your theme**
>
> The easiest way is to start with either the default style or one of
>   the example styles included in the Colorbox JS library download.
>   Simply copy the entire style folder to your theme and rename it to
>   something logical like "mycolorbox". Inside that folder are both a
>   .css and .js file, rename both of those as well to match your folder
>   name: i.e. "colorbox_mycolorbox.css" and "colorbox_mycolorbox.js"
>
> Add entries in your theme's .info file for the Colorbox CSS/JS files:
>
> ```
> stylesheets[all][] = mycolorbox/colorbox_mycolorbox.css 
> scripts[] = mycolorbox/colorbox_mycolorbox.js
> ```
>
> Go to "Configuration" » "Media" »
>   "Colorbox" and select "None" under "Styles and Options". This will
>   leave the styling of Colorbox up to your theme. Make any CSS
>   adjustments to your "colorbox_mycolorbox.css" file.